# Is there an edge case for EF6 to not persist to db, but no exceptions thrown

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-6

I have a weird edge-case that happens probably less than 1% which I can't wrap my head around a possible cause or replicate.

A Xamarin forms mobile app calls an endpoint to insert data into the db, if successful everyone is happy, if not, retry later - the tech stack of the API is a bit old, MVC 5 and entity framework 6, but shouldn't be a problem.

The endpoint has some fundamental fixes needed, but showing for completeness:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(SubmitDataDTO submitData)
{
    db = new DBContext();
    try
    {
        var parentId = Guid.NewGuid();
        foreach (var childItem in submitData.Children)
        {
            var child = new Children()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                ParentId = parentId,
                //properties..
            };
            db.Children.Add(child);
        }

        var parent = new Parent()
        {
            Id = incomingId,
            //properties..
        };

        db.Parent.Add(parent);

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
    catch (System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException ex)
    {
        //LOG VALIDATION ERROR
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //LOG ERROR
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
    }

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

The mobile app side is also pretty straight forward, if *response.IsSuccessStatusCode* is true, mark the submission as successfully processed. What we are seeing is that the mobile app is showing it was successfully submitted, but the data isn't available on the server.

Only explanation I can see, there is either an edge case where the SaveChanges doesn't persist with no exception and the OK is sent, or there is some edge case where IIS/endpoint sends an success, but the endpoint was never processed. I'm really stumped.

Comment: According to your description, you mean that data is not saved to the database, there is also no any error message?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Correct, I left out the nLog code in the catch, but no exceptions or nLog entries that I can see. But in any case, an internal server error would have been sent to the app, and not flagged as successful. I didn't add that the app data packet has an external GUID identifier, so that I can track it much easier, but also flag duplicate submissions.

Comment: According to your code, can not know what is problem, maybe you can take a look sample about [using ef core in xamarin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/xamarin).